# kubelet_volume_stats_* in Kubernetes 1.17

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, metrics, kubelet

I've been monitoring my k8s cluster in Azure with Prometheus/Grafana with no problem till last update from v1.15 to v1.17. Now I can't kubelet_volume_stats_* metris in Prometheus, and I have no idea why.

Reading https://v1-17.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/notes/#deprecated-changed-metrics I've seen these metrics have been marked as with the ALPHA stability level.

What's the meaning of this? Is there a way to continue reading these metrics from Prometheus?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can view node utilization by using:

```
node_filesystem_avail
node_filesystem_free
node_filesystem_size
```

For [PersistentVolumeClaims](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/persistentvolumeclaim-metrics.md) you can use following metric:

```
kube_persistentvolumeclaim_resource_requests_storage_bytes
```

Comment: So with kube_persistentvolumeclaim_resource_requests_storage_bytes I obtain pvc size... and is there any metric to get used/free size for that PVC?